# how to test playframework's tag and do I need do that

Tags: playframework, functional-testing

When I create new playframewor's tag. Do I need make test for that (assuming that we use TDD)? And how it is possible and what it the best practice doing tests for tags in general?

For example there is a piece of code where I use my tag "my_tag":

```
#{my_tag param1:value1, param2:value2 }
```

If think about tag a little.. it is just piece of presentation that renders something on the page that would use. Then we should test how it handle parameters and how it render it to html?

Answer (score 0):

How is `my_tag` implemented? As an html/tag file or in code as a FastTag?

If my_tag is defined in an html/tag file the general guidance is you don't want to put a lot of logic in them. So maybe you would be better testing/validating the source of value1 and value2 and making sure my_tag never gets a bad value1 or value2 (assuming you have pretty tight control of who is using my_tag.

If my_tag is implemented in code as a FastTag, that code can be as complex as you want. In that case, you would want to write tests that exercise all the execution paths in the FastTag logic. You could do that just having a test page of:

```
#{my_tag param1:badvalue1, param2:value2 }
#{my_tag param1:value1, param2:badvalue2 }
#{my_tag param1:badvalue1, param2:badvalue2 }
#{my_tag param1:value1, param2:value2 }
....
```

to test as many happy and sad paths for my_tag as you can.